# Does a chordal graph with singleton minimal separators have a special name?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider a [chordal graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph) $G$. Chordal graphs are precisely the graphs that admit a clique tree representation. A clique tree $T$ has as its vertices the maximal cliques of $G$. Edges in $T$ are minimal separators.

Assume a chordal graph $G$ and its clique tree $T$, where each edge corresponds to a minimal separator of size precisely one. A [1-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree) is a special case. My requirement is relaxed: the cliques can be of any size as long as the minimal separators are singletons.

> Does a graph like this have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is known as a [*block graph*](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_93.html). That is, a graph is a block graph if it can be constructed from a tree by replacing every edge by a clique of any size. Furthermore, any two cliques have at most one vertex in common (the minimal separator is of size 1 as required).